# How do I create a function that is when I click the delete, it will ask me... in html

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create a function that is when I click the delete, it will ask me, if I click YES it will delete and, I click NO it won't delete and still stay that page.
I am using FLASK.
Here are my coding

```
    <a href ="http://127.0.0.1:5000/delete/{{ row.number}}"><button class="button button2" style="float: right; font-size:30px;" onclick="deletefunction()">Delete it</button></a>
    <script>
        function deletefunction() {
           if (confirm('Do you want to delete it?')) {
               yourformelement.submit();
           } else {
               return false;
           }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the jinga code :

```
<form action={{ url_for('delete_function') }} method=post>
    <input type=hidden name="row_number" value="{{ row.number }}">
    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('{{ 'Are you sure to delete ?'}}');return false;">{{"Delete"}}</button>
</form>
```

and in a working example:

```
from flask import Flask,request,abort,render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    return render_template_string("""<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Test</title></head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            {% for number in [0,1,'b']%}
            <h2>{{ number }}</h2>
            <form action={{ url_for('delete_function') }} method=post>
                <input type=hidden name="row_number" value="{{ number }}">
                <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('{{ 'Are you sure to delete ?'}}');return false;">{{"Delete"}}</button>
            </form>
            {% endfor %}
        </body>
    </html>
""")

@app.route("/delete-function", methods=["POST"])
def delete_function():
    row_number =  request.form['row_number'][:20]
    try:
        int_row_number = int(row_number)
    except ValueError:
        return abort(404)
    return "Trying to delete row "+str(int_row_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```